# In Windows Server 2012, I could not find a driver for Ethernet Controller?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I installed windows server 2012 in vMware. **Ehternet cards are working in my physical PC but in vMware windows server 2012 I do not see any network adapter** and ***ethernet controller*** has no driver. Check the attached screenshot and please guide me.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSS8p.png)

Regards,

Comment: Did you install VMware tools in the guest?

Comment: You may want to read up on the basics of virtualization to understand why the Ethernet card in your physical PC has nothing to do with the network adapters you see in your VM. You may then want to consult VMware's documentation to find out how to configure virtual NICs for VMs.

Comment: it shows **Unavailabe vMware tools**. By the way, I am using vMware 10 so I don't know if it supports windows 2012 for everything.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in your windows' device manager, Ethernet cards are attacked to the vm machine. You should install the appropriate driver to Ethernet cards get work.
Installing vmware-tools is the best and easiest solution.

Comment: I installed vmware 11 and then installed vmware tools. It is working now.

Comment: Please accept this answer to help other people will get your problem in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server has only drivers for the E1000 NIC. If you want to use VMXNET NIC you must install VMware Tools.